# Vuetify grid layout - How to fill height of element in grid

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, grid-layout, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a grid layout but am having trouble.

The layout I'm trying to create is attached in the image below. It's easier to show than explain.

- A side panel card layout that will be filled with a list of items. A
- 2 element top panel.
- A big main panel to fill the remaining space
  underneath.

[image: Current Layout]

Using the vuetify grid layout system, i've tried to get it but can't get it to nicely fill out all the space. My code is below.

Is there a nice way to create this grid layout?

```
<v-container fluid grid-list-md box>
  <v-layout row>

    <v-flex d-flex xs3>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 90) }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 90) }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 90) }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 90) }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-layout>

    </v-flex>

    <v-flex d-flex xs9>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex d-flex>
            <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
              <v-card-text>{{ lorem }}</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex d-flex>
            <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
              <v-card-text>{{ lorem }}</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>

        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex d-flex xs9>
            <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
              <v-card-text>{{ lorem }}</v-card-text> 
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-layout>

    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that format by using the fill-height prop and the breakpoints. Having `<v-layout row wrap>` will force the larger box with `xs12` to take up the entire next row, so you don't have to create it's own layout.

```
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex d-flex xs6>
          <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex d-flex xs6>
          <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem + lorem }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex fill-height d-flex xs12>
         <v-card color="blue-grey" dark tile flat>
           <v-card-text>{{ lorem + lorem + lorem}}</v-card-text>
         </v-card>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/twandy/pen/oPJdeQ) that shows it in action.

Comment: Why are you specifying the `d-flex` attribute on a `<v-flex>` component? Is this not entirely redundant?

Comment: It's required for the nested grids. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#nested-grid

Comment: Things seem to have changed with the [latest Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#nested-grid) (v2). No mention of `d-flex`.